# Automate task to convert SPSS file (.spv) to PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf, spss, rpa

I'm looking for a way to quickly convert a folder containing multiple SPSS Output files (.spv) to PDFs. Ideally I would like to do this with Python, but if there is an easier solution, I'm all ears.

I really just need the .spv file to open in python, then click File -> Export -> PDF.

I've never tried my hand at automating tasks before in any language, so I'm at a loss for how to even begin this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone with a similar question: I wasn't able to build an elegant converter or anything, but I did find an easy solution to just open up each file and click File -> Export -> PDF for me. I did this using [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html)

Here is my code for anyone interested.

```
from glob import glob
import pyautogui 
import subprocess
import os
import time
import signal

all_files = glob("C://Users//directory//*//*")

screen = pyautogui.size()

#Confirm that your screen is 1920 X 1080
#If not, you'll need to change some of these dimensions
if screen == (1920,1080): 
    for file in all_files:
        if file.endswith('.spv'):

            #Have SPSS already open for this to work
            p = subprocess.Popen(file, shell=True) #open file

            #left to right 0 to 1920
            #up to down 0 to 1080
            pyautogui.moveTo(22, 50, duration=2) #File
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.moveTo(22, 230) #Export
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.moveTo(650, 250) #Choose 'All Visible' option
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            pyautogui.doubleClick(800, 820) #Ok

            try: 
                time.sleep(5) #Let SPSS Export, this takes time

                #Rename the 'Output.pdf' file
                #The "output_directory" is just where SPSS is saving your files
                current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file))
                os.chdir("C://Users//output_directory")

                for filename in os.listdir("C://Users//output_directory"):
                    if filename.startswith("OUTPUT.pdf"):
                        base = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file))
                        renamed, file_extension = os.path.splitext(base)
                        renamed = renamed + '.pdf'
                        os.rename(filename, renamed)

            #Close SPSS file
            pyautogui.click(2875, 5) #File
```